# Weibull Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I need some help I've been trying to solve a problem for a couple of hours in which they give me the mean= 45 and the variance=35^2 of a weibull distribution, I'm supposed to find the parameters beta and delta. How can I find the parameters beta and delta, I tried to do it by solve in MathCad but it isn't working. The Gamma in the lower part is supposed to be Gamma^2  [image: This is what I have so far]

Comment: You should check your values for variance and mean, because the the final result that you produced should be an integer as the $Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$. If that were to be the case, the final result reduces to ${(\frac{2}{\beta})\choose(\frac{1}{\beta})}$ which should be an integer by all means unless if I am mistaken badly about gamma function?

Answer (score 0):

To give some general information regarding Mathcad and solving for an unkown, you would need to use the Given...Find block.  In your instance (assuming your original derivation is correct), you would need to perform the following:

[image: Given...Find]